# AttributeError while using plac: 'Namespace' object has no attribute

Tags: python, namespaces, argparse

Trying to write a command line function, and I've been stymied by this AttributeError. I know that other people have asked similar questions but I haven't seen any using plac so I figured I'd write this out.

```
@plac.annotations(
    training_file=("The filename containing the text you wish to annotate", "option", "-tf", Path),
    entity_type=("The name of the entity you wish to annotate", "option", "-e", str)
)
def main(training_file=None, entity_type=None):
    """Script to more easily annotate spaCy NER training examples"""

    if not training_file:
        training_file = input("Please enter the filename of the data you wish to annotate: ")
        with open(training_file, 'r') as training_file:
            list_to_annotate = training_file.read()

        print(list_to_annotate)
```

and where it's run:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    plac.call(main)
```

There's more to my actual command, but whenever I run this I get the same error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Steve\PycharmProjects\GroceryListMaker\model_scripts\training_data_maker.py", line 79, in <module>
    plac.call(main)
  File "C:\Users\Steve\PycharmProjects\GroceryListMaker\lib\site-packages\plac_core.py", line 367, in call
    cmd, result = parser.consume(arglist)
  File "C:\Users\Steve\PycharmProjects\GroceryListMaker\lib\site-packages\plac_core.py", line 230, in consume
    args = [getattr(ns, a) for a in self.argspec.args]
  File "C:\Users\Steve\PycharmProjects\GroceryListMaker\lib\site-packages\plac_core.py", line 230, in <listcomp>
    args = [getattr(ns, a) for a in self.argspec.args]
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'training_file'
```

I'm really not sure what's wrong, and it's making me tear my hair out here. Any help greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace it with:

```
@plac.annotations(
    training_file=("The filename containing the text you wish to annotate",
        "option", "tf", Path),
    entity_type=("The name of the entity you wish to annotate", "option", "e", str)
)
```

it works (note that I removed the `-` in the abbreviations).

In the future you can use pdb to track down problems like this more quickly.  Here's what I did:

```
$ python -m pdb main.py
> /home/embray/src/junk/so/60005716/main.py(1)<module>()
-> import plac
(Pdb) cont
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pdb.py", line 1667, in main
    pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pdb.py", line 1548, in _runscript
    self.run(statement)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/bdb.py", line 434, in run
    exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/embray/src/junk/so/60005716/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import plac
  File "/home/embray/.virtualenvs/tmp-954ecd64f7669c29/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plac_core.py", line 367, in call
    cmd, result = parser.consume(arglist)
  File "/home/embray/.virtualenvs/tmp-954ecd64f7669c29/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plac_core.py", line 230, in consume
    args = [getattr(ns, a) for a in self.argspec.args]
  File "/home/embray/.virtualenvs/tmp-954ecd64f7669c29/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plac_core.py", line 230, in <listcomp>
    args = [getattr(ns, a) for a in self.argspec.args]
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'training_file'
Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging
Running 'cont' or 'step' will restart the program
> /home/embray/.virtualenvs/tmp-954ecd64f7669c29/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plac_core.py(230)<listcomp>()
-> args = [getattr(ns, a) for a in self.argspec.args]
(Pdb) up
> /home/embray/.virtualenvs/tmp-954ecd64f7669c29/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plac_core.py(230)consume()
-> args = [getattr(ns, a) for a in self.argspec.args]
(Pdb) p ns
Namespace(e=None, tf=None)
```

Here you can see that your argument namespace was replaced with `e` and `tf`, suggesting that somehow putting a `-` in the abbreviation actually replaces the argument name (this was just a guess on my part but it turned out to be correct).

I'd consider that a bit of a bug on plac's part--it's very confusing and the documentation doesn't indicate anything about this.

Comment: Wow, you're a lifesaver -- it works! My first introduction to pdb too; I would never have caught this otherwise. Thank you so much!

Comment: I always try to push pdb onto beginners, because the more comfortable you get with it the easier it will be for you to debug problems like this, even in other peoples' code.

Comment: Looks like `plac` is trying to be too "smart" with the options.  I was introduced to `argparse` via `plac` years ago (in Py 2.4 days), so it's been around for a long time.  But it is a one man project.  With `argparse` I encourage people include a `print(args)` debugging so they see the `Namespace` without assumptions; but that's not directly accessible here.

Comment: `click` seems to be the most popular alternative to `argparse`, at least among those wanting a more user-friendly front end.